# No-Javascript Detection Script + Redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I would like to write a script that detects whether the user has javascript disabled, and if yes, redirect them to another page (let's say mysite.com/enablejavascript)

However, I have no idea where to start! Thanks SO.

Comment: You'll need to use `<noscript></noscript>`

Comment: @BrianDriscoll. Why didn't you write it an answer? it has the most upvotes!

Comment: If JavaScript is disabled,  how exactly would you get your script to run?

Answer (score 26):

Gdoron mentioned noscript already. Together with [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)¹ you can redirect users if they have JavaScript disabled.

A JavaScript redirect can be done with [`location.replace(URL)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

```
<head>
  <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/without-js" />
  </noscript>

  <script>
    location.replace('http://example.com/with-js');
  </script>
</head>
```

Example of noscript+meta refresh: http://pastehtml.com/view/bsrxxl7cw.html

1) Mind the [drawbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks) section of the Wikipedia article!

> Meta refresh tags have some drawbacks:
>
> - If a page redirects too quickly (less than 2-3 seconds), using the "Back" button on the next page may cause some browsers to move back to the redirecting page, whereupon the redirect will occur again. This is bad for usability, as this may cause a reader to be "stuck" on the last website.
> - A reader may or may not want to be redirected to a different page, which can lead to user dissatisfaction or raise concerns about security.

Comment: +1. didn't know that `Meta refresh` thing. Nice. I added the drawbacks to your answer. Hope you don't mind

Comment: OK This seems to work fine for me. However Visual Studio claims that noscript cannot be embedded in head and that meta cannot be embeded in noscript. My DOCTYPE is

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

and the html tag has the namespace

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Are either of these related?

Comment: HTML5 allows meta-tags anywhere in the document.  They are among other things used for microdata on schema.org. HTML5 also allows noscript in head as long as it only contains among other things, meta.

Comment: note that meta refresh is not remcommended for accessibility which is usually why someone might not have javascript turned on.

Answer (score 4):

How do you want to write a script when java-script is disabled... ?

It's can not be done. You can show a message when javascript is disabled with `<noscript>`.

`<noscript>` tag on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript):

> The HTML NoScript Element () defines a section of html to be inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is currently turned off in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You should combine HTML redirect in a noscript element. I found this [JavaScript redirection](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) generator. Here is your sample code:

```
<!-- Pleace this snippet right after opening the head tag to make it work properly -->

<!-- This code is licensed under GNU GPL v3 -->
<!-- You are allowed to freely copy, distribute and use this code, but removing author credit is strictly prohibited -->
<!-- Generated by http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/ -->

<!-- REDIRECTING STARTS -->
<link rel="canonical" href="https://yourdomain.com/"/>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://yourdomain.com/">
</noscript>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "https://yourdomain.com/";
    if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
    {
        document.write("redirecting..."); // Don't remove this line or appendChild() will fail because it is called before document.onload to make the redirect as fast as possible. Nobody will see this text, it is only a tech fix.
        var referLink = document.createElement("a");
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
    }
    else { window.location.replace(url); } // All other browsers
</script>
<!-- Credit goes to http://insider.zone/ -->
<!-- REDIRECTING ENDS -->
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this: If java script is disabled then display a php link

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write("<button type='button' onclick='somefunction()' >Some Text</button>"); 

</script>

<noscript> 

<?php echo "<a href='redirectfile.php'>Some Text</a>"; ?> 

</noscript>
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)