# Slideshow when Javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I created the following slide show:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/V8fZr/

I have two questions:

1. I would like to know how I can create this exact same slide show without Javascript as a fall back for browsers with disabled javascript... or also for just older browsers in general. Any ideas?
2. Not as high priority.. but there is a weird bug in FireFox. When I load the page, if I click refresh, the slider doesn't load the first image. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Without JS, you'd need another scripting (like Flash) for any "slide" effects (CSS3 not counted :-). Otherwise, you have to use different pages to load or just simple anchor navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.It isn't possible to create a slideshow in HTML4 and CSS2 as they are static - you need javascript or other dynamic language to implement effects. The best you can do is develop it so it will degrade gracefully (e.g. arrange each slide on the page in an easy-to-view layout).

HTML5 & CSS3 will let you do this, but its not fully supported in many major browsers (i.e. IE!) and javascript support is more common than HTML 5 support.

2.You have some syntax errors in your HTML which may be causing your problem in FF (I haven't tested this code, but you need to fix them either way)

```
<div class="slide">
<img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/6olzzo.png" width="450px" height="285px" />
</div> <!--this was missing -->
<div class="slide">
<img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/ftdc7o.png" width="450px" height="285px" /> <!-- you were missing end quote on src attribute --> 
</div>
<div class="slide">
<img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/6olzzo.png" width="450px" height="285px" /> <!-- you had extra end quote on src attribute -->
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... how can you create a button that toggles the slide with HTML5?

Comment: @user1090389 Its not just a matter of changing a line of code or a few tags - HTML5/CCS3 is conceptually very different to HTML4 and CSS3, and depending on your requirements you may still need javascript to trigger events. And you'll still need to gracefully handle non-HTML5/CSS3-compatible browsers. You really will reach a much wider audience with JS, especially as you specifically want it to work in older browsers (which a HTML5/CSS3 solution definitely won't - it won't even work in many new browsers)

Comment: Hey thanks so much FluffyKitten. How would you recommend going about degrading gracefully? In other words - how do you create fallbacks for older browsers?

Comment: @Ori it really depends on your application and what you want to do. The simplest solution is to just arrange the slides one after another/in a grid depending on size etc. using CSS, and then use the javascript to override the CSS layout for your slideshow to work. Another option is to detect that javascript isn't supported and redirect to a page with the 1st slide, which will link to another page with the next slide etc. (Obviously use a single dynamic page like php instead of creating a static page for each)

Comment: "Another option is to detect that javascript isn't supported and redirect to a page with the 1st slide, which will link to another page with the next slide etc. (Obviously use a single dynamic page like php instead of creating a static page for each)" - I love this idea... do you think you can maybe redirect me to a link on how to achieve both of these goals? 

1. Detecting java script isn't supported and redirecting to a different page
2. Setting up the dynamic page with sub pages

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Detect & redirect is easy as HTML provides <noscript> tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895012/no-javascript-detection-script-redirect The rest is more difficult as you dont seem to have php development experience? It will display slide X where X is the slide num, & a link to "next slide" which is actually a link to itself passing the next slidenum on the querystring. If each slide consists only of an image, you could rename the images to be the slide num & check for the file named the required number. A Google search should turn up some PHP tutorials if you need them. Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for all your thoughtful help. I REALLY REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: No prob! Come back & post a new Q if you have specific questions about the dynamic page if you decide to go that way.